# Pandas: Calculated field can't be greater than value from another field

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a calculated field (spend) where the value of this field cannot be greater than another field (budget). The spend field is calculated based on two other fields (`CPM`, `Impressions`) with the formula `((Impressions/1000)*CPM)`.

I've created the spend field using the following:

```
df['spend'] = df['CPM']*(df['Impressions']/1000)
```

From there, I'm not able to find a solution to apply an if/else condition to the rows within the spend field. If `spend > budget`, row value should be replaced with the corresponding value from budget. Else, pass and retain the calculated value within spend.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) or [`min`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.min.html) with subset of columns:

```
df['spend'] = df['spend'].mask(df['spend'] > df['budget'], df['budget'])

df['spend'] = df[['spend', 'budget']].min(axis=1)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'spend':[1,2,8],
                   'budget':[4,5,6]})

print (df)
   budget  spend
0       4      1
1       5      2
2       6      8

df['spend'] = df['spend'].mask(df['spend'] > df['budget'], df['budget'])
print (df)
   budget  spend
0       4      1
1       5      2
2       6      6
```

---

```
df['spend'] = df[['spend', 'budget']].min(axis=1)
print (df)
   budget  spend
0       4      1
1       5      2
2       6      6
```

Comment: Thank you! The Series.mask version solved the problem exactly!

Answer (score 1):

Just get the minimum value:

```
df['spend'] = np.minimum(df['spend'], df['budget'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another NumPy solution:

```
df['spend'] = np.where(df['spend'] > df['budget'], df['budget'], df['spend'])
```